# Is there a way to add a variable to a list and sort it, but keep the list at the same range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

`list = [3,3,4,6,7]` In my case, this list will already be in order.
`New value = 5`
How do I put `5` between the `4` and the `6` but kick out the other `3` so that the list is `[3,4,5,6,7]`? In this way, the list would stay at 5 values long.
Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How do you decide which value to kick out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply reassigning the corresponding indexes?

```
lst = [3,3,4,6,7]

lst[1], lst[2]= 4, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
new_value=5
list = [3,3,4,6,7] 

#sort the list
list=sort(list)

if new_value<= list[0]:
    #add new value at the beginning of list and remove the last element of list
    list.append(i)
    list=list[:-1]
if new_value>list[0] and new_value<list[-1]:
    #add new value at the beginning of list, re-sort the list and remove the first (or last) element of list
    list.append(i)
    list=sort(list)
    list=list[1:] #remove the first element
    #or to remove the last element
    # list=list[:-1]
if new_value>=list[-1]:
    #add new value at the beginning of list, re-sort the list and remove the first element of list
    list.append(i)
    list=sort(list)
    list=list[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when you decide which value to kick out, is this what you looking for?
This will always return you with the last 5 items of your new list after sorting it

```
list = [3,3,4,6,7]

list.append(5)

newList = [item for item in sorted(list)][-5:]

>> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```